# XFCE keyboard shortcut Ctrl-Alt-Left

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

Is there a way to disable XFCE capturing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd> and let other apps using it?
Can it be done without restarting XFCE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Settings->Window Manager->Keyboard. Scroll down to Left Workspace and click on a "Clear" button. Repeat for a Right Workspace.

Comment: For me (Linux Mint 21)  was in Settings Editor > xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts > xfwm4 > custom > <Control><Alt>Right